# Was the fake Witch’s Ghost in Scooby Doo and the Witch’s Ghost meant to be Sarah Ravencroft?

Tags: scooby-doo

Since it was based on the story of Sarah Ravencroft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversation in the film is slightly different in the [tie-in storybook](https://archive.org/details/scoobydoo8x800gail), but the sentiment seems to be same, e.g. that the ghost was absolutely supposed to be her.

> "We found Sarah’s gravestone when we built our Puritan Village" the mayor went on.
> "We remembered how she'd been accused of witchcraft. So **we used her as our ghost**. But we didn't find that journal."

Note that there are images of Sarah around town, including a portrait. The puritan hat is, however, pure fiction.